# Mochiweb Log files

Tags: erlang, mochiweb

Anyone know where Mochiweb logs files by default?  I'm running it along with the Beepbeep framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mochiweb reports errors via the [error_logger](http://erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html), so you can either write your own handler, or start [SASL](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sasl_app.html), and configure it to write a log file.

Comment: To start SASL in current VM add `-boot start_sasl` to parameters of the `erl`

Answer (score 0):

Aren't they kept in the priv directory next to mochiweb's start script?

Edit: Never mind, I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Mochiweb does not create log files as you would think it would. If you want to have apache-like logs, you'll have to roll your own.